# Slow postgres query

Tags: postgresql

I have a query on a table with almost 40mio rows and its getting slower and slower. Even if I do a simple:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as count_air FROM "airplay_airplay";
it's taking almost 12s to output 37428412
```

Any ideas where to look for improvements? Thanks in advance

```
Finalize Aggregate  (cost=621262.92..621262.93 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=12207.175..12207.359 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=480 read=424843
   ->  Gather  (cost=621262.71..621262.92 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=12203.426..12207.339 rows=3 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=480 read=424843
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=620262.71..620262.72 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=12172.089..12172.090 rows=1 loops=3)
               Buffers: shared hit=480 read=424843
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on airplay_airplay  (cost=0.00..581274.77 rows=15595177 width=8) (actual time=0.487..11179.857 rows=12476137 loops=3)
                     Buffers: shared hit=480 read=424843
 Planning Time: 0.082 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 11
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 1.109 ms, Inlining 164.849 ms, Optimization 73.269 ms, Emission 39.649 ms, Total 278.877 ms
 Execution Time: 12207.961 ms
(16 rows)
```

The table is 8 columns with mainly integer fields and a few date fields.

```
   Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                   Default
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------
 id         | bigint                   |           | not null | nextval('airplay_airplay_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_at | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 updated_at | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 airedAt    | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 duration   | integer                  |           | not null |
 radio_id   | bigint                   |           | not null |
 song_id    | bigint                   |           | not null |
 playcount  | integer                  |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "airplay_airplay_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "airplay_airplay_radio_id_f0670674" btree (radio_id)
    "airplay_airplay_song_id_d1d128db" btree (song_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "airplay_airplay_radio_id_f0670674_fk_airplay_radio_id" FOREIGN KEY (radio_id) REFERENCES airplay_radio(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "airplay_airplay_song_id_d1d128db_fk_core_song_id" FOREIGN KEY (song_id) REFERENCES core_song(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Comment: Thank you @LaurenzAlbe

I added the output in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The query execution time is just the time it takes to sequentially read the table. There is nothing substantial that you can speed up here; [counting rows *is* slow](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/postgresql-count-made-fast/).

Some ideas:

- Use `count(*)` rather than `count(id)`. That has the same result, but is slightly faster.
- perhaps refreshing the visibility map can result in a faster index-only scan:

  ```
  VACUUM airplay_airplay;
  ```
- The table seems somewhat bloated. If you can take the down time to run

  ```
  VACUUM (FULL) airplay_airplay;
  VACUUM airplay_airplay;
  ```

  that might speed it up a bit.
- if an approximate result is good enough, run

  ```
  SELECT reltuples FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'airplay_airplay';
  ```

  That will be lightning fastt.

Comment: The real problem is that I want to select artist that don't have airplay and therefore I have to join all 40mio rows. And that one is realllly slow.

Comment: There is no join in your query. That would be an entirely different query, and you should ask another question with your actual query.

Comment: thank you @laurenz I will ask a new question.

Comment: New question -> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/310393/query-on-joined-large-table-very-slow

@laurenz-albe