# query on joined large table very slow

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to get all artists that didn't have airplay listed. But the airplay table is around 40Mio row. This seems to make this query very slow. It takes exactly the amount of time of a count of the airplay table. (56s) btw on my local machine the query takes 12s.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  COUNT(*) as count_artist 
FROM "core_artist" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "core_song_artists" 
 ON ("core_artist"."id" = "core_song_artists"."artist_id") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "core_song" 
 ON ("core_song_artists"."song_id" = "core_song"."id") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "airplay_airplay" 
 ON ("core_song"."id" = "airplay_airplay"."song_id") 
WHERE "airplay_airplay"."id" IS NULL;
```

Any ideas how to optimize this?

This is the query plan:

```
                                                                             QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=1532171.18..1532171.19 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=54285.626..54285.638 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=5917 read=490587 dirtied=4614 written=40, temp read=120535 written=120535
   ->  Sort  (cost=1532171.18..1532171.19 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=54285.624..54285.635 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: (count(*))
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
         Buffers: shared hit=5917 read=490587 dirtied=4614 written=40, temp read=120535 written=120535
         ->  Aggregate  (cost=1532171.16..1532171.17 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=54285.537..54285.547 rows=1 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=5914 read=490587 dirtied=4614 written=40, temp read=120535 written=120535
               ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=45830.00..1532171.16 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=48719.697..54281.840 rows=64906 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (airplay_airplay.song_id = core_song.id)
                     Filter: (airplay_airplay.id IS NULL)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 10005964
                     Buffers: shared hit=5914 read=490587 dirtied=4614 written=40, temp read=120535 written=120535
                     ->  Seq Scan on airplay_airplay  (cost=0.00..852772.20 rows=37408720 width=16) (actual time=1.634..39582.868 rows=37428412 loops=1)
                           Buffers: shared read=478685
                     ->  Hash  (cost=42854.55..42854.55 rows=181316 width=8) (actual time=1635.876..1635.883 rows=236433 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 131072 (originally 131072)  Batches: 8 (originally 4)  Memory Usage: 3631kB
                           Buffers: shared hit=5914 read=11902 dirtied=4614 written=40, temp read=2636 written=3174
                           ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=33116.46..42854.55 rows=181316 width=8) (actual time=1287.764..1587.410 rows=236433 loops=1)
                                 Hash Cond: (core_song_artists.song_id = core_song.id)
                                 Buffers: shared hit=5914 read=11902 dirtied=4614 written=40, temp read=2636 written=2636
                                 ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=5825.98..11587.12 rows=181316 width=8) (actual time=773.181..916.504 rows=236433 loops=1)
                                       Hash Cond: (core_song_artists.artist_id = core_artist.id)
                                       Buffers: shared hit=2753 read=1848 dirtied=371, temp read=493 written=493
                                       ->  Seq Scan on core_song_artists  (cost=0.00..3136.16 rows=181316 width=16) (actual time=0.034..45.770 rows=181756 loops=1)
                                             Buffers: shared hit=235 read=1088 dirtied=36
                                       ->  Hash  (cost=4242.88..4242.88 rows=96488 width=8) (actual time=771.881..771.883 rows=91764 loops=1)
                                             Buckets: 131072  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 2822kB
                                             Buffers: shared hit=2518 read=760 dirtied=335, temp written=156
                                             ->  Seq Scan on core_artist  (cost=0.00..4242.88 rows=96488 width=8) (actual time=647.340..736.293 rows=91764 loops=1)
                                                   Buffers: shared hit=2518 read=760 dirtied=335
                                 ->  Hash  (cost=18544.99..18544.99 rows=532999 width=8) (actual time=513.717..513.718 rows=533003 loops=1)
                                       Buckets: 131072  Batches: 8  Memory Usage: 3626kB
                                       Buffers: shared hit=3161 read=10054 dirtied=4243 written=40, temp written=1591
                                       ->  Seq Scan on core_song  (cost=0.00..18544.99 rows=532999 width=8) (actual time=0.022..350.060 rows=533003 loops=1)
                                             Buffers: shared hit=3161 read=10054 dirtied=4243 written=40
 Planning Time: 58.792 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 28
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 2.537 ms, Inlining 194.253 ms, Optimization 245.291 ms, Emission 205.470 ms, Total 647.551 ms
 Execution Time: 54678.764 ms
(42 rows)
```

Comment: You forgot to add the plan...

Comment: You mean the table descriptions @LaurenzAlbe?

Comment: No, the result of the `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: I added it to the original question.

Comment: What is the plan on your local machine? If it is faster on your local machine, why not just run it there?

Comment: You should turn on track_io_timing and then collect the plan again.

Comment: When you run the same query over and over, it is usually with different parameters.  But this query has no parameters.  Why do you care if it takes a minute to run?  Who is going to just sit there and run this over and over again?

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, you have to rewrite your query so that it actually does what you need. That may already improve the performance. Then you can try to make it faster.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM core_artist AS ca
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM core_song_artists AS csa
                     JOIN core_song AS cs
                        ON csa.song_id = cs.id
                     JOIN airplay_airplay AS a
                        ON cs.id = a.song_id
                  WHERE ca.id = csa.artist_id);
```

But if the tables are large, that will never be lightning fast. The best you can do is crank up `work_mem` as high as you can to get hash joins and avoid temporary files wherever possible.

Comment: Thank you! I have 4GB of RAM. What would think ```work_mem``` can be? 10MB? 4GB/4/100

Comment: That depends on how much RAM is taken by shared buffers and how many concurrent sessions you allow. You can change the setting for a single query.